# AWS Ruby SDK v2 Stack filtering

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-cloudformation

My question is: "Is there any possibility to create server-side filter to sort Stacks by tags?"
I'm trying to use v2 ruby SDK. So, any kind of help would be great.

Thanks, Sergey

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for the Ruby SDK to request stacks filtered by tags. The Amazon CloudFormation ListStacks API only supports filtering stacks by status. You can view the API for ListStacks here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/APIReference/API_ListStacks.html